# How can I adjust the operational tension of a Delta shower faucet?

Tags: plumbing, repair, shower, bathroom-fixtures

My Delta Monitor 1300/1400 series faucet was repaired by a neighbor because it dripped from the shower head. Now it works and there is no leak but it's waaaay too easy to push. Like you touch it with slight pressure and it flies over to the hot or cold whichever way you touch it.

Answer (score 1):

The cartridge for that shower model contains all the moving pieces internally:

[image]

It isn't like some cartridges that rotate inside the faucet body.  Since the moving parts are inside the sealed unit, there's not much you can do to make it tighter.

It's possible that a low-cost replacement cartridge was used instead of a genuine OEM part.  My suggestion would be to get a name-brand Delta replacement cartridge and install that.  Since it was recently repaired, it should be an easy fix (cartridge shouldn't be stuck or anything), but you will need to turn off the water to do it.

Comment: It says that it's a genuine Delta part. I got it off of Amazon. The bottom is not blue though it's cream. I wonder if I should get a replacement?

Comment: I just picked an image to show what the valve looked like in general.  Yours could be a different color.  Even if it was a Delta valve, I guess the one you got could have been too loose.  You might try to find another one.